What is Concatenation of paths?
I saw similar definitions both in Topology and Complex analysis, but are introduced in different ways.
From topology course, we define path as a continuous function from $[0,1]$ to $X$, and concatenation as
$\gamma_1 *\gamma_2 = \begin{cases} \gamma_1(2s), & 0 \leq s \le \frac{1}{2} \\
\gamma_2(2s-1), & \frac{1}{2} \leq s \le 1
\end{cases}$
However, in complex analysis, a path is a representative element of the equivalence class of parametrizations. For example, I can choose a representative $\gamma$ from $[a.b]$ to $\Bbb{C}$.
How to concatenate two paths in complex analysis? I can always choose a representative $\gamma$ from $[0.1]$ to $\Bbb{C}$. (For example, by $\gamma' = \gamma(\frac{t-a}{b-a})$, and then mimic the way defined above. However, if I need to give a general definition without transforming to the $[0,1]$ path first, how can I do? And why?

Assuming $\gamma_1: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}, \gamma_2: [c,d] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, and $\gamma_1(b)=\gamma_2(c)$.
Define $\gamma_1 \star \gamma_2 : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ as
$$\gamma_1 \star \gamma_2 (t):= \begin{cases} \gamma_1(a+(b-a)2t) & \text{if } t\leq \frac{1}{2} \newline
\gamma_2(d+(d-c)(2t-1)) & \text{if } t > \frac{1}{2}\end{cases}.$$

The choice seems arbitrary? I mean we can define it in any way? Or we can only do it as you defined here?

It's partly arbitrary.  For example, instead of dividing $[0,1]$ into $[0, \frac12] \cup (\frac12, 1]$ we could divide it into $[0, x] \cup (x, 1]$  for any $x$ between $0$ and $1$.   And we don't need to require that the domain $[0,1]$ be exactly that interval; it could be any closed interval. All this is because, as you said, a path is a representative element of the equivalence class of parametrizations.

@Andrew_Ren: As you noted in your question, what you really care about is the equivalence class of paths, defined up to a reparameterization.

@Andrew_Ren Did the others answer your questions already, or do you still have a question? I'd be happy to answer them.
